# Why xiaomi mi10 is not recognized using adb\fastboot in fastboot mode?

Tags: mobile, adb, xiaomi, fastboot

Both Ubuntu and Windows recognize my mi10 phone on normal startup, but when I've enter fastboot (Power+Vol Down) to burn a new rom, it is undetected by either adb\fastboot, I've enabled usb-debugging and OEM Unlocking of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting good couple of hours, 
It turns out you need to go the mobile device **"Developer options" --> "Mi Unlock status"**
 Grant permission to "Mi Unlock" a utility by xiaomi that can be downloaded from [here](http://www.miui.com/unlock/index_en.html) (works on Windows).

this app will unlock your xiaomi device, making it possible to burn a new rom.

For me I had to wait 168 hours (1 week) before the app unlocked my phone (An excessive security measure?)